# Bind widget to Menu Key

Tags: tkinter

How can I bind a widget to the Menu Key on the keyboard? The key I'm referring to is the one that is usually **between** the right Alt and Right Ctrl keys (if you're using a PC). It's meant to bring up a right-click context menu when you press it.

To see what the Menu key looks like, please see this Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key

So far I've tried this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_press(event):
    print(event.keycode)
    
root = tk.Tk()

root.bind("<KeyPress>", on_press)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run that code in Linux and press the Menu key on the keyboard, it outputs 135. So the keycode that I want to bind to is keycode 135. How can I bind to keycode 135 or more specifically: the Menu key on the keyboard?

Comment: In Windows, use `<App>`.  I don't know whether it is the same in Linux.

Comment: @acw1668: in Linux, root.bind("<App>", on_press) gives me an error: bad event type or keysym "App"

Comment: at the very least you can do a simple `if event.keycode == 135:`

Comment: Try `print(event.keysym)`.

Comment: @acw1668: That helped. event.keysym gave me the word: Menu. So I put root.bind("<Menu>"...) and that worked. If you put that as an answer (event.keysym) I can accept it.